# How to format values inside MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

2 Questions about the [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
All my yvalues are integers, but displayed as Decimals.
How can I get them displayed as integers (without the digits)?
How can I prevent that the ylabels are also shows as decimals?
I know there is a setFormatter for the yvalues, just don't understand how to use...

Comment: Have you solved it out?
i mean... what did you put inside the getFormattedValue() method of the ValueFormatter interface?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at the `IValueFormatter` [interface](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/) provided by the library. With that interface, you can completely customize what gets displayed on the chart based on your own logic.

Usage:

```
chart.setValueFormatter(new YourValueFormatter());
YLabels yl = chart.getYLabels();
yl.setFormatter(new YourValueFormatter());
```

**UPDATE** (for versions **2.0.0+** of this [library][2]):

Now, a `ValueFormatter` can be set for each `DataSet` separately, **or** the same `ValueFormatter` can be set for the whole data object containig all `DataSets`. Furthermore, the `YLabels` class is now called `YAxis`.

Example:

```
// set for whole data object (individual DataSets also possible)
LineData data = new LineData(...);
data.setValueFormatter(new YourValueFormatter());

// YLabels are now called YAxis
YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft(); // get the left or right axis
yAxis.setValueFormatter(new YourAxisValueFormatter());
```

**UPDATE** (for versions **3.0.0+** of this [library][2]):

The interfaces for formatting have been renamed and extended in their functionality. Now, the `IAxisValueFormatter` can be used to format values of both `XAxis` and `YAxis`. The `IValueFormatter` interface is used to customize chart values.

Link to the [ValueFormatter documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/).

Comment: Aahhhh, now I get it. Very nice and simple solution!

Comment: Phil, since when do YLabels support the setValueFormatter() method? I'm trying to do the same but there is no such method...(I need the LargeValueFormatter()) for my case, and it doesn't seem to work if I set the LargeValueFormatter(). to the chart itself either.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the library (1.7.4)? https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases

Comment: I'm pretty sure I do. I updated the library on the 24th of November. And your latest release was on the 18th.

Comment: First. I just noticed that the method name is changed for the YLabels to setFormatter(new YourValueFormatter()). You should update your answer as well so others won't be distracted as well. Thanks!

Comment: Cutting off decimal positions doesn't change the labels correctly - after having 2.0 - 2.4 it changes to 2 - 2 (duplicates). Any ideas on how to correct it?

Comment: i used this a variable with NumberFormat type and set it into "NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();" but still returned the Decimal once it's rendered. Any clues @JamesCameron ?

Comment: return Math.round(value)+""; in getFormattedValue worked for me!

Comment: @PhilippJahoda how do I send my ArrayList which has x-axis labels to the axis value formatter. I've used `xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart));` which sets date as Jan 1st, Jan 2nd not the dates which I have

Comment: I'm using `xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-30f);` which is adjusting the date based on the space and slanting it a bit, so that labels doesn't overlap. Amazing library @PhilippJahoda

Comment: what if i want to replace numbers with string label? please suggests for it

Comment: same question as @AnandSavjani

Comment: @PhilippJahoda The link to the IAxisValueFormatter points to a 404, could you fix this?

Comment: @Abby updated, both data and axis use the same formatter now

Comment: _PercentFormatter_ class has 2 different constructors. Empty constructor did 
 not help me although I used percent mode. If `pieData.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());` doesn't show percentage icon, you should use second constructor like that : `pieData.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(pieChart));`

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to change the number of decimal places on the values, the
`DefaultValueFormatter` will suffice.

```
pieDataSet.setDefaultValueFormatter(new DefaultValueFormatter(digits = 1))
//where digits is the number of decimal places
```

The example above will format 88.65 as 88.7