# How to show only data value instead of percents in piechart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using Android MPChart library in my Android project. Where I want to show only data value on pie chart.

I tried with

```
chart.setUsePercentValues(false);
```

but it shows actual value with % symbol.
I want to remove that % symbol. How to remove % symbol?

Also if possible, I would like to show data in legend.

Code for Pie Chart

```
        chart.setUsePercentValues(false);
        chart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);
        chart.setHoleRadius(60f);
        chart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        chart.setRotationAngle(0);
        chart.setRotationEnabled(true);

        chart.setDescription("");

        chart.setDrawSliceText(false);

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals, "");
        dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);

        dataSet.setColors(colors);

        /**Set data to piechart */
        PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        chart.setData(data);

        chart.setDescription("");
        chart.highlightValues(null);
        chart.animateXY(1500, 1500, AnimationEasing.EasingOption.EaseOutBack);
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true);



        Legend l = chart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        l.setYEntrySpace(5f);

        chart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Please post the code. Also, what version of MPAndroidChart you are using?

Comment: @ganesh,I am using libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-0-9.jar, Kindly see code.

Comment: What exactly you want do with the legends? Without any configuration I see the legend displayed with the color and text.

Comment: I want to show color- text-value format in legend.

Comment: I see that legends are shown without doing any configuration.There are lots of settings of chart in your code. Possibly something is interfering with the default behavior.

Comment: Dear Ganesh,Legend are already drawn in my chart,with format color-text.I just want to add values to this format.So it will look like color-text-value.         eg. red - apple - 10,   where 10 is quantities of apple

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Comment the line

```
data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
```

Percentage will go away.

Comment: Thank you ganesh,It worked.But it shows values in float. i.e if value it 5 then it display as 5.0, How to display only 5?

Comment: I think, a formatter may be helpful for this. I have not tried this.

Comment: oh ok Thank you. I found some on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883298/how-to-format-values-inside-mpandroidchart

Comment: @GaneshKumar How do I include both percentage and value?

Comment: `chart.setUsePercentValues(true); data.setValueFormatter(new SomeFormatter());` Like this??

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this,

          PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);

           data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter() {

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry,int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {

                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBaseaxis) {

                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {

                return 0;
            }
        });
```