# How do I add a unit to the value labels in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to attach a unit to the value labels. How do I do that?

[image: A bar chart with the value labels circled and "+km" written next to the first]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format values inside MPAndroidChart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883298/how-to-format-values-inside-mpandroidchart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by writing an implementation of [`IValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) as in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883298/how-to-format-values-inside-mpandroidchart) :

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return mFormat.format(value) + " km";
    }
}
```